# Поверка метода на исключения(Exceptions)

Tags: java, исключения

хотелось проверить получение параметров на их валидность и выбросить исключение с соответствующим описанием ошибки, для этого как я понимаю нужно создать метод типа:
`private void checkArguments(тут аргументы для проверки)` и в методе с кодом перед работой нужно как-то вызывать этот метод для проверки

```
    public class Cook extends Human {
    public Cook() {
        super();
    }

    public Cook (String name) {
        super (name);
    }

    public void cook (ArrayList<Food> fl, String name, Veget veget) {
        int rand = new Random().nextInt(4);
        Food f = new Food(name);
        switch (rand) {
            case 0: f.setTaste(Taste.SWEET); break;
            case 1: f.setTaste(Taste.SOUR); break;
            case 2: f.setTaste(Taste.SALTY); break;
            case 3: f.setTaste(Taste.BITTER); break;
        }
        f.setVeget(veget);
        fl.add (fl.size(), f);
    }

    public void eat(ArrayList<Food> foodList) {
        if (!foodList.isEmpty()) {
            Food f = foodList.get (foodList.size()-1);
            foodList.remove(foodList.size()-1);
            Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle ("Вкусно!");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Кажется, вкус этого блюда: " + f.tasteToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
                    "Овощ: "+ f.getVeget().vegetableToString().toLowerCase() +", цвет блюда: " + f.getVeget().colorToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
                    "В следующий раз приготовлю вкуснее");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

я понимаю, внутри метода `private void checkArguments` нужно проверять на несоответствие. Пример из листа:

```
private void checkIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Incorrect index output...");
        }
    }
```

как это применить к методу `cook` или `eat` ?

Comment: О каком методе идет речь? И что означает "неправильные параметры" в данном примере? Единственный претендент на "неправильность" это листы, которые могут быть `null`. Но наверное вы что-то другое подразумеваете... И вообще, я же вам отправлял вариант без этих ужасных свичей и магических чисел. И зачем `add(index,item)`, если обычный `add(item)` добавляет в конец списка!

Comment: В принципе речь идёт о двух методах cook и eat,  да тоже думал о проверке на nall, думаю она имеет место быть, но других идей пока нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну в принципе любые проверки параметров делаются одинаково

```
void cook(ArrayList<Food> foodArrayList, String ItemName) {
    if (foodArrayList == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // or
    Objects.requireNonNull(foodArrayList); // throws NPE if null

    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.nextInt(Taste.values().length);
    Taste t = Taste.values()[r];
    Food f = new Food(t, ItemName);
    foodArrayList.add(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый метод это проверка до передачи в метод, т.е. еще в источнике - валидация.
Второй проверка и регистрация throw. http://sernam.ru/book_java.php?id=45

Comment: а что подразумевается под проверкой и регистрацией throw  во втором методе ?